# Встроенная функция sum(). Не работает для списка списков

Tags: python

Если интересно, то задача возникла из необходимости объединить коды цветов точек в один список. То есть у меня 3n точек, идущих последовательно n штук одного цвета.  Естественно, я воспользовал автогенерацией (comprehensive list):

```
cc = [n * [color, ] for color in ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green'] ]
```

Например при n == 2 получим:

```
cc

Out[24]: 
[['tab:blue', 'tab:blue'],
 ['tab:orange', 'tab:orange'],
 ['tab:green', 'tab:green']]
```

теперь очевидно

```
cc[0] + cc[1] + cc[2]
Out[25]: ['tab:blue', 'tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:green']
```

однако желаемое применение встроенной функции `sum()` приводит к прерыванию.

```
sum(cc)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-175665ff078b> in <module>
----> 1 sum(cc)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Не понимаю   -  о каком "инте" здесь идет речь.
Протрите мне глаза пжста....

Выход я нашел:

```
import itertools
[el for el in itertools.chain(*cc)]
Out[33]: ['tab:blue', 'tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:green']
```

Однако как говорит Хеттингер - "Должен быть лучший путь".  Ведь `sum()` должна бы работать, не правда ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sum(iterable, start)
>
> Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of
> numbers

У `sum` есть параметр - начальное значение, с которым складывать элементы. По умолчанию там `0`, поэтому выходит такая ошибка. Но там можно прописать пустой список, и всё сработает:

```
sum(cc, [])
```

Comment: Я в захвате.
Я  знал параметр, но пробовал поставить 0,
А почему  -  пустой список надо подставить??  Если можно чуть смысла добавить.  )))

Comment: Я похоже до сих пор не понимаю этого английского теста.
Я читал это место перед тем как пробовать по их же совету `itertools.chain`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Ну потому что нужный вам вид арифметики работает именно для списков, именно при сложении списков элементы пристыковываются.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
a я думал старт - это с какого индекса начинать считать....
.
Дякую!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Ну, слово `numbers` тут запутывает, да. Просто чтобы списки "сложились" надо начинать сложение со списка. А чтобы лишнего ничего не получилось в итоге - нужно начинать именно с пустого списка, конечно.

Comment: `'start' value` - start тут "значение", не индекс, конечно

Comment: Ответ хороший, тема ужасная. Не надо применять `sum` к спискам. Код выглядит изящно и привлекательно. Но это квадратичный алгоритм! Попробуйте `len(sum([[i] for i in range(100000)], []))`.